# Change action based on which button opened Activity?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to make an app that asks the user maths questions. I have a number of buttons, such as multiplication, addition etc. I want my code to have a series of if/else statements that tells it what operator to use based on which button was clicked in the previous activity.

What do I use to access this information?

Comment: are you using more than one activity?.

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/build-a-calculator-app-721910/ this seems to be a helpful tutorial on building a simple android calculator app

Comment: @Anil I have two activities - one with the multiplication/addition buttons, the to other is just to ask the questions. I was hoping to be able to use the same activity for all the different types of operation, and just alter the Java slightly.

Comment: so you want to know in second activity which button pressed in First activity

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the button id in the intent. Like this;

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("button_id", buttonID);
context.startActivity(i);`
```

Then in your Activity;

```
Intent I =get intent();
Int buttonID = intent.getIntExtra("button_id");
```

Comment: sorry! new here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass argument to You activity using Extra and perform some actions based on its value.

```
int extraValue = 5;

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", extraValue);
startActivity(i);
```

Then You can obtain this extra by its name in your target activity.

```
extraValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_NAME", -1); // here -1 is default value.
```

Comment: `getExtras().getInt()` versus `getIntExtra?`

Answer (score 0):

A new activity is always started by an intent. If we want to start an activity with some information, we can put the same in that intent which is used to start it. This intent can be caught by getIntent() method in started activity.

Example:

In your first activity:

```
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    switch(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
        case R.id.add:
            intent.putExtra("operator","add");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.subtract:
            intent.putExtra("operator","subtract");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.multiply:
            intent.putExtra("operator","multiply");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.divide:
            intent.putExtra("operator","divide");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
```

And in your second activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    intent = getIntent();
    String operation = intent.getStringExtra("operator");

    switch(operation){
        case "add":
            //your code
            break;
        case "subtract":
            //your code
            break;
        case "multiply":
            //your code
            break;
        case "divide":
            //your code
            break;
    }

}
```

}